# Electrical current fuse utilizing two PNP transistors not working

Tags: fuses, pnp

I have been trying for some time to get a modified current fuse design I found on the internet to work, with no luck.

It should function as such:

Current flows through the second transistor, that has its base connected to the ground, and so stays open (PNP.) When the current through a sense resistor reaches high enough value, the voltage on the resistor gets high enough to start opening the first transistor. This lowers the output voltage, whitch leads to a voltage differential between the output and the first transistor base through the 5000ohm resistor, opening it fully. All current will then pass through the first transistor and then through a resistor into ground.

[image]

This presumably is happening in my physical circuit, the problem I am facing it that the fuse trips way too soon.

I am trying to make a 1A fuse, with 30V input voltage (1*0.56 -> aprox. transistor opening voltage.) The circuit in the image trips at around 0.4A.

I have been trying various things, individually changing the values of all the resistors in the circuit.

Changing the 1000 ohm base resistor of the first transistor increased the trip current, to about 0.6A, which I frankly do not understand.

Lowering the value of the sense resistor doesn't have the expected effect, the trip current changes only very little (I tried to about 0.4ohm.)

Interestingly, when I short the position where the sense resistor should be, meaning the first transistor should not be able to open, the circuit just doesnt work at all.

I am at a loss, especially since the circuit works perfectly in the simulation, with transistors very similar to ones actually used. There's very clearly something that I am fundamentally misunderstaning.
[image]

EDIT:
So am back from the testing. I had some succes with this edited schematic:[image]

With this, the circuit trips at 0.85A. I dont have a easy way to precisely change the sense resistor value, but i think that 1A should be achievable. Another issue however presented itself. The second transistor has a rather large voltage drop on it at this value, at 20V input in excess of 1.5 V. At 30 V, this is likely to get significantly larger. Problem is that the transistor (which i forgot to specify, is BCP53-10) isnt able to handle such wattage. To keep the second transistor more open, R3 would have to be lowered further. This however compromises the fuse function, since I actually made a mistake in the design. There should be another resistor between T1 colector and T2 base, to limit the current in the tripped state that "I forgor" to add. This truly has been a failure at all fronts. Ill be changing the transistors out for a higher power variety, and put two large resistors in parallel as R3, for which theres at least space.
I thank everyone for all the answers, hopefully Ill be more observant in the future.

Comment: Just a couple of suggestions - #1: label your schematic (Q1, R3, etc) so we don't have to guess which part you're referring to. #2 Don't use word like "open" & "closed" to describe transistor behavior. It's sometime difficult from the context to work out if you mean "open like a gate" or "open-circuit which does not conduct". Words like "conducting", "switched/turned on" are unambiguous.

Comment: What transistor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of circuit is a "bit" complicated to analyse.

Here is what I found with the original picture and values, after choosing BJT.
As you can see, max current is not what one expect ...

[image]

Here is the new "circuit" after some resistors choice
(interactive simulation done with [microcap v12](https://web.archive.org/web/20200218212700/http://spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm)).
Parameters are R2 and R5. Max current is really function of R5.
R2 adjust "somewhat" the "foldback" current.

[image]

NB: Transient analysis must be done to check "results". (added ... later).

Comment: Oh wow! That much more complete answer than I expected, thanks a lot! I will try to play with the resistor values in the actual circuit the next time i get a chance, based on those values.

Comment: If you try it at the lab, keep us informed ... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The DC gain of your upper, main path PNP is less than you expected. The output voltage drops before the trip point at the shunt resistor is reached. This can invoke enough base current in the lower control PNP via the 5k resistor and trigger the shutdown. Allow more base current for your main PNP to compensate.

Another solution is a darlington PNP in the main path.

Comment: This does clear things up a bit. This circuit really is quite a bit trickier than it first seemed to me. Thanks for the reply!